# Batch script to launch an application

Tags: windows, batch

I've a simple batch script npp.bat to open a file in Notepad++

```
"C:\Program Files\(x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %1
```

Notepad++ launches with the file when I run `npp <file_name&gt>` but the command window waits for the application to exit. I don't want it to wait.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `start` instead:

```
start "" "command here"
```

**Edit:** Do not miss the first pair of empty quotes, this is the title of the process/window.

```
start <title> <command> <parameters>
```

See `start /?` for further details.

Comment: That starts a new console window and the script runs there. I just want to start Notepad++ with the file and nothing else. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @CodingTales Be sure to include the first set of empty quotes.

Comment: I missed the first "" and it didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to be able to do "npp file.txt" on the command prompt and be able to edit files using Notepad++. For this, I created a new folder, added it to Windows PATH, and created a file there called npp.bat with the following content:

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %1
```

Very useful when I'm working on the console and need to edit a file.

Comment: if your text editor is associated with txt files then won't it launch your text editor if you just type file.txt  even without the npp? btw i have a similar setup with my text editors.. maybe even an npp.bat when I used notepad plus!  You may want the %1 in quotes. in case the filename has a space, and you could experiment with a %* though no doubt you'd see if you had an issue an amend accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

@Bobby method should work, If you directly calls the batch script ( double click ), the method will open a new command window. Instead use the following,

```
@echo off
start "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" blah.txt
cls
exit
```

If you replace `blah.txt` with `%1`, then you should pass the argument when you call the batch file.

Comment: Missing the first set of quotes in the start command. That will open a new window with the title C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe and execute bla.txt

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but 3 out of 4 lines of this script are unnecessary, in my eyes especially the `exit`. I hate people who put that into their scripts, because then I always have to restart the terminal from which I executed it. :/