# Using Launchy to open executable with notepad++

Tags: batch, notepad++, launchy

I'm trying to find an easy way using launchy to open files via n++ that might not normally be that way. For example, if I have an authohotkey (`ahk`) file that I want to edit, I'd like to be able to use a script or command to launch it in notepad++.

I think there might be a way to do this with batch looking at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/160865/batch-script-to-launch-an-application) question, but I'm not sure how to make it so I can call it in launchy with the file name.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that you don't really need Launchy to open random files in Notepad++. The batch file linked in you original question supports simply dropping files onto it to open them in that program. The quick version of this would saving a batch file on your desktop with `START notepad++ %*`.

Comment: That actually helps a bunch, thank you. I'll have to mess around with it to see the best way to deal with paths, but I really appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Glad I could assist. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the information given by Anaksunaman, I was able to come up with what appears to be a workable solution.

I created a bat file in the directory I want to search through that simply says

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /S /b %*') do SET FNAME=%%i
START notepad++ %FNAME%
```

This will search through the directory of the file as well as any subdirectories.

This isn't really directly related to Launchy, but it does work when launched through Launchy.